# replace a for loop, but with which apply statement?

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I'm attempting to replace some very complex **for** loops with apply statements in old legacy code.  This is a small example for loop as an example

```
old.array <- c(15:24)
new.array <- old.array

for (i in 4:length(old.array)) {
    new.array[i] <- old.array[i-2] + old.array[i-3]
}
```

Any suggestions on which way to go to replace this with an `apply` (or `plyr`) function would be most helpful.  The problem for me arises from the placeholder such as **[i -2]** in the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to a for loop or any of the `apply(...)` functions.

```
len <- length(old.array)
new.array <- old.array
new.array[4:len] <- old.array[2:(len-2)] + old.array[1:(len-3)]
```

@SvenHohenStein's comment below is correct. In the revised code above the vectors are the same length (len-3).

Comment: Almost correct, 1 small spelling error, arrray -> array but the other thing is that requires brackets around `len-2` and `len-4` as `(len-2)` and `(len-4)`

Comment: Yes absolutely. Thanks.

Comment: How do you add two vectors of different length?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it:

```
new.array <- c(old.array[1:3], 
               filter(head(old.array, -2), c(1, 1), sides = 1)[-1])
# [1] 15 16 17 31 33 35 37 39 41 43
```